# Reshaping a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I am trying to use melt amb cast to transform this data frame

```
 knowngene                                           Meth
 uc003fia.3 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193
 uc003cha.4 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193
 uc003fhz.4 cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
 uc003fhz.4 cg00000132;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
 uc003fia.3 cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
 uc003fia.3 cg00000236;0.799251070221749;0.898656886868738
```

In something like this

```
 knowngene                                           Meth
 uc003fia.3 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193;cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076;cg00000236;0.799251070221749;0.898656886868738
 uc003cha.4 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193
 uc003fhz.4 cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076;cg00000132;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
```

But for a particular reason I couldn't reshape the data frame, maybe changing to a list first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need `aggregate()`:

First, your data:

```
myDF <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "knowngene   Meth
uc003fia.3 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193
uc003cha.4 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193
uc003fhz.4 cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
uc003fhz.4 cg00000132;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
uc003fia.3 cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
uc003fia.3 cg00000236;0.799251070221749;0.898656886868738")
```

Second, the aggregation:

```
aggregate(Meth ~ knowngene, myDF, paste, collapse=";")
#    knowngene                                                                                                                                         Meth
# 1 uc003cha.4                                                                                               cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193
# 2 uc003fhz.4                                                cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076;cg00000132;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
# 3 uc003fia.3 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193;cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076;cg00000236;0.799251070221749;0.898656886868738
```

Answer (score 2):

Split and apply will get you close:

```
lapply(split(x$Meth, x$knowngene), paste, collapse="; ")

$uc003cha.4
[1] "cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193"

$uc003fhz.4
[1] "cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076; cg00000132;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076"

$uc003fia.3
[1] "cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193; cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076; cg00000236;0.799251070221749;0.898656886868738"
```

The result is a named list with all of the text concatenated in the way you wanted.  You can convert it to a data frame using `names()` and `unname()`:

```
data.frame(knowngene=names(x), Meth=unlist(unname(x)))

   knowngene
1 uc003cha.4
2 uc003fhz.4
3 uc003fia.3
                                                                                                                                            Meth
1                                                                                                 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193
2                                                 cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076; cg00000132;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076
3 cg00000108;0.864484486796394;0.928944704280193; cg00000109;0.881060551674426;0.910939682196076; cg00000236;0.799251070221749;0.898656886868738
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cast(knowngene ~ ., data = your.data.frame, value = "Meth", 
    function = paste, sep = ";")
```